# Force iOS notifications to show alert buttons without swipe or force touch

Tags: ios, swift, audio, notifications, ios10

I have an iOS app which plays a long (20s) audio at some schedules. The problem is if alert style is set to BANNER ( Alert style in unlocked mode in iPhone settings) then audio plays for just about 5s and then the notification hides and audio playback terminates. How can I keep alert visible until end of audio playback?

Other people have same problem:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/185451#185451

Answer (score 0):

Although one cannot force a banner notification to stay visible for more than 5 seconds, they can make a limited amount of actions persist in the background. For example, Whatsapp or Snapchat makes your phone keep on vibrating if you receive a call after the alert is gone. I do not know if sound can be made to persist after the banner alert disappears but I'm sure Apple Developer Support can direct you to where you need to go. There phone number is: 18006332152

Hope you find a well-trodded path! Good luck my friend.

Comment: Whatsapp & SnapChat use VOIP feature for rining in background, it's not a normal notification.